# Android: make Firebase Auth avaiable to all the activities

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to make `Firebase Auth` avaiable to all the activities?
Maybe using an `intent` or something?

Answer (score 6):

The Firebase Authentication data is already available to all activities. You just need to look it up with the API.

If you *know* the user is already signed in:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

If you don't know whether the user is signed in yet, use an `addAuthStateListener()` listener:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
        // ...
    }
});
```

Both come from the [documentation on getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).